# Python requests не подключается к http(s) прокси

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Всем привет, есть код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


with open("proxy.txt") as file:
    proxy = file.readlines()


def checkProxy(address):
    try:
        headers = {
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0"
        }
        proxies = {
            "http": f"http://{address}",
            "https": f"https://{address}"
        }
        r = requests.get("https://whoer.net/ru", proxies=proxies, timeout=5, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
        ip = soup.find("strong", class_="your-ip").text.strip()
        return ip

    except Exception as e:
        return e


def main():
    for address in proxy:
        print(checkProxy(address.strip()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

По идеи он должен подключатся к проси и выдавать ip который получил. Но вместо этого весь список прокси выдает ошибку при подключении. (даже если брать свои приватные прокси он все ровно не подключается) Ошибка:

> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='whoer.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded
> with url: /ru (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL:
> WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1129)')))

Нагуглил и там было сказано поставить urlib последняй версии, но если я его заменяю в requests то сама либа requests ругается что нет urlib

Comment: Ошибка не в самом коде, а в SSL соединении. Версия слишком старая.

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему. Надо было удалить модули requests и urllib3, а потом установить их с этими версиями:

```
pip install requests==2.4.2
pip install urllib3==1.25.11
```